# Where does entry_point script is stored in custom Sagemaker Framework training job container?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create my own custom Sagemaker Framework that runs a custom python script to train a ML model using the entry_point parameter.

Following the Python SDK documentation (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html), I wrote the simplest code to run a training job just to see how it behaves and how Sagemaker Framework works.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly build my Docker container in order to run the entry_point script.

I added the `train.py` script into the container that only logs the folders and files paths as well as the variables in the containers environment.

I was able to run the training job, but I couldn't find any reference of the entry_point script neither in environment variable nor the files in the container.

Here is the code I used:

- **Custom Sagemaker Framework Class:**

```py
from sagemaker.estimator import Framework

class Doc2VecEstimator(Framework):
    def create_model():
        pass
```

- **train.py:**

```py
import argparse
import os
from datetime import datetime


def log(*_args):
    print('[log-{}]'.format(datetime.now().isoformat()), *_args)


def listdir_rec(path):
    ls = os.listdir(path)
    print(path, ls)

    for ls_path in ls:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, ls_path)):
            listdir_rec(os.path.join(path, ls_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument('--debug_size', type=int, default=None)

    # # I commented the lines bellow since I haven't configured the environment variables in my container
    #     # Sagemaker specific arguments. Defaults are set in the environment variables.
    #     parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR'])
    #     parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    #     parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    log('Received arguments {}'.format(args))

    log(os.environ)

    listdir_rec('.')
```

- **Dockerfile:**

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        nginx \
        ca-certificates \
    && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
    && \
    pip3 install \
        numpy \
        scipy \
        scikit-learn \
        pandas \
        flask \
        gevent \
        gunicorn \
        joblib \
        pyAthena \
        pandarallel \
        nltk \
        gensim \
    && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE

COPY train.py /train.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-u", "train.py"]
```

- **Training Job Execution Script:**

```
framework = Doc2VecEstimator(
    image_name=image,
    entry_point='train_doc2vec_model.py',
    output_path='s3://{bucket_prefix}'.format(bucket_prefix=bucket_prefix),

    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    train_volume_size=5,

    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    base_job_name='gensim-doc2vec-train-100-epochs-test',

    hyperparameters={
        'epochs': '100',
        'debug_size': '100',
    },
)

framework.fit(s3_input_data_path, wait=True)
```

I haven't found a way to make the training job to run the `train_doc2vec_model.py`. So how do I create my own custom Framework class/container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SageMaker team created a [python package `sagemaker-training`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit) to install in your docker so that your customer container will be able to handle external `entry_point` scripts.
See here for an example using Catboost that does what you want to do :)

https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-byo-catboost-container-demo

Comment: Thanks, @Olivier_Cruchant. I will try this out and see what happens!

Comment: you can also see a nice explanation of how framework containers work here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/custom-training-containers